# Can I make the webview take only a part of the screen?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make a webview to open on the bottom of the application to display little information but it keeps taking the whole screen and covering other widgets with information.
Is there a way to make it have a certain size and place on the application?

Comment: show us some XML view defintions

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you should provide some of your layout xml so we can see what your are wrapping the webview inside. Is your webview the root element of your app layout - than it will always use the full screen. But try wrap it inside a framelayout or something else...

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom">
  <WebView
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```